# Linux server backup with PHP?

Tags: php, backup, exec

I manage a VPS of my client. He wanted a backup solution includes some folders and mysql databases. OS is Ubuntu, web server is apache. I don't want my client to mess with ssh or ftp.

I think i can save database backup files and trigger PHP's exec function from a wab page to zip folders and database backup files, then give a link to download this zip file.

This is technically possible but i wonder if there is a better solution except automatically copying backup files to another server. Because creating backups anytime is required in my situation.

Comment: Do you have Cpanel? If yes, try http://docs.cpanel.net/twiki/bin/view/11_30/CpanelDocs/BackupWizard

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are lots of possibilities, here is a very simple one we use every day:

- create a backup script (e.g. in bash) with the usual suspects as mysqldump, tar and date
- make sure, this backup script locks against double runs
- create a cron job, that runs every minute, checks if a flagfile exists, and if yes starts the backup script and then clears the flagfile
- if you want, create more cron jobs (e.g. a daily one), that do nothing but set the flagfile
- create a trivial PHP script, that just touches the flagfile to trigger an adhoc backup
- You can download the finished backup package, once the flagfile is cleared (again check via a trivial PHP script)

Comment: My only quibble about this is why schedule the job every minute? I did something very similar where the cron job was rescheduled daily at 03:00 and sat in a sleep loop polling the touch file every 15s until the 03:00 roll-over and then opening a PHP cgi script on activation to read and action a job request table in MySQL.  This plus a simple requestor / status / pull script effectively gave and-users a sandboxed web admin access to such batch functions.

Comment: The difference between a "sleep loop polling background job" and a "once per minute cronjob" is mostly academic: You can see `cron` itself as being "sleep loop polling". I chose the cronjob for robustness: If you reboot the server at 03:05, flagfile polling will start immediately with the cron approach, but only 23:55 hours later with the approach you described. In short: cron does, what is needed (apart from being minute-granularity only), I don't want to reinvent the wheel